# Система не распознает Django файл

Tags: python, django

Если я пытаюсь сохранить этот django файл:

```py
from django.urls import path
import django.views  
    
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='main-view')
```

Я получаю ошибку :

> Name 'views' is not defined

Если я пытаюсь поменять `import django.views` на `from . import views` (как во всех видео уроках) я получаю ошибку :

> Attempted relative import with no known parent package

У меня есть файл `init.py` с командой `import django.views`. Если я меняю эту команду на  `import views` (как во всех видео уроках) то я получаю ошибку:

> Unable to import "views"

Содержимое файла views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h4>Hello</h4>")
```

Структура проекта :

```
|__Django
 |__firstsite
  |__firstsite
   |__ __pycache__
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ asgi.py
   |__ settings.py
   |__ urls.py
   |__ wsgi.py
  |__main
   |__ __pycache__
   |__ migrations
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ admin.py
   |__ apps.py
   |__ models.py
   |__ tests.py
   |__ urls.py
   |__ views.py
  |__db.sqlite3
  |__manage.py
```

C чем могут быть связаны все эти проблемы ?

Comment: Покажите структуру проекта и содержимое файла `views.py`. Добавьте эти данные в текст самого вопроса

Comment: "У меня есть файл init.py с командой import django.views" - в каком именно каталоге это находится? А лучше все таки привести описание всей структуры проекта - каталоги и файлы в них. А еще лучше взглянуть на сам проект целиком где-нибудь на gitlab \ github

Comment: Ошибка происходит потому, что у вас в файле не определено имя `views`, только `django.views`, попробуйте `from main.views import views`. Но кажется это не единственная проблема. Как увы запускаете проект? Возможно главная ошибка в этом.

Comment: from main.views import views - ошибка: No name 'views' in module 'main.views'. Я запускаю только отдельные файлы кнопкой 'Run Python File in terminal'.

Comment: @WandPoint этот файл `urls.py` находится в `firstsite` или в `main`?

Comment: И в firstsite и в main есть файлы с названием urls.py .

Comment: Нет, именно тот, который представлен в тексте вопроса. От его расположения зависит то, как должны импортироваться файлы проекта.

Comment: В вопросе находиться urls.py из main.

Comment: Попробуйте `from main import views`. При импорте вы указываете `from <модуль> import views`, но, если файлы находятся внутри **одного** модуля, вместо названия ставится `.`

Comment: from main import views - ошибка: No module named 'main'.

Comment: А просто import views  работает ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `from main import views`

Answer (score 0):

Как потом оказалось , проблемы , как таковой , и не было. Просто VSCode видет какие-то части кода Django , как ошибку , хотя сайт написанный на Django полностью рабочий.